# Sample file not availabe for junit test case

Tags: java, maven

I have to do junit 5 test case for file reading. Files I kept n test/resource folder. When I give mvn clean build. All the test resources are cleaned. File is not available for junit testcase. Can some one help me to fix the issue.

Comment: Are you using the command `mvn clean test` ? In this way you combine clean with "test" phase, where all the resources are put back in classpath, and all Test classes are compiled and executed. If this is the issue, please let me know, i will put it in the answer

Comment: If you correctly located a file in `src/test/resources/` you would like to use within your unit test you can access that via `class.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/filename")` and continue to work within your Test class with it...

Comment: Yes I m using mvn clean test. Also I did class. getClass(). Getresource() --->here I m getting null pointer

Comment: My resource folder is cleaned up. No files available during testing